# Does idea have a feature like "allow output folders for source folder" in myeclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, myeclipse

I use Intellij IDEA to develop a web project and I have some source folders in the project.

I want to compile code in different source folders to different compile folders.

I know in myeclipse there is a feature "allow output folders for source folder" which can achieve this goal,  but I can't find the function in Intellij IDEA, so I wonder if there is one or is there a convenient way to realize it.

Comment: What you want? Did you want to store class files in other folder outside eclipse mentioned path?

Comment: I use intellij idea to develop a web project   and  have some source folders in the project , i want to compile code in different source folders to different compile folders.

Comment: Do you mean `code generation` ? Perhaps even generation of java code from an `xsd` file, or the like? In such a case you should be able to define extra `source roots`.

Comment: This is only a problem about IDE settings, maybe I didn't express it clearly because of my poor English ,but I think CrazyCoder get what I want to say ,and gave out the answer below. I am sorry if I confused you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by splitting your code into multiple modules in IntelliJ IDEA as output folder configuration is provided only for modules, not per source root/folder.